# Grails 2.2.1 does not recognize the "release" plugin is installed from BuildConfig.groovy

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I need to use the Grails "release" plugin in 2.2.1 and I add it to the plugins in my BuildConfig.groovy below:

```
    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2", ":cors:1.1.0"
        compile ':cache:1.0.1'
        build ":release:2.2.1"
    }
```

I try to run the maven-deploy:

```
$ grails prod maven-deploy --repository=releases --verbose --non-interactive
| Loading Grails 2.2.1
| Error WARNING: Configurational method [:release:2.2.1] in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy doesn't exist. Ignoring..
| Error WARNING: Configurational method [build] in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy doesn't exist. Ignoring..
| Running pre-compiled script
| Error Script not found: MavenDeploy
```

OR (when changing from build to compile in BuildConfig.groovy):

```
| Running pre-compiled script
| Error Script not found: MavenDeploy
```

I try to list the plugins the release plugin is not there:

```
$ grails list-plugins --installed
Plug-ins you currently have installed are listed below:
-------------------------------------------------------------
cache               1.0.1            --  Cache Plugin
common-domain       1.2.4            --  Common Domain Plugin
cors                1.1.0            --  CORS Plugin
database-migration  1.3.2            --  Grails Database Migration Plugin
hibernate           2.2.1            --  Hibernate for Grails
jquery              1.8.3            --  JQuery for Grails
resources           1.1.6            --  Resources
tomcat              2.2.1            --  Apache Tomcat plugin for Grails
webxml              1.4.1            --  WebXmlConfig
```

I got it to work using the deprecated install-plugin target. 
I have no idea why this is not working and would like to know if anyone can shed some light on it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that $GRAILS_HOME environment variable is set and points to the correct location on your file system.

Answer (score 3):

After adding the entry in `BuildConfig.groovy` for `release` plugin, do a `grails compile` or just `grails run-app`. I normally prefer `grails clean && grails compile`.

Once cleaned and compiled, you can check the installed plugin list
`grails list-plugins --installed`

It has been working for me. :-)